# Onclick to open activity from adapter of fragment not working

Tags: java, android, fragment

I am trying to run some code I got from some online tutorial of writing a fragment with a recyclerview in it but I am experiencing some difficulty in opening an activity from the onclick event. My adapter is below

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private final ArrayList<ItemModel> mArrayList;
    private Context mcontext;

    ItemAdapter(ArrayList<ItemModel> mArrayList) {
        this.mArrayList = mArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        mcontext = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listing_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //Glide.with(mcontext).load(mArrayList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.item_image);

        holder.item_name.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.item_description.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.item_tags.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getTags());

        Log.d("MyAdapter", "position: " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mArrayList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private final ImageView item_image;
        private final TextView item_name;
        private final TextView item_description;
        private final TextView item_tags;
        private final LinearLayout cardViewLayout;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            item_image = view.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            item_name = view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            item_description = view.findViewById(R.id.item_description);
            item_tags = view.findViewById(R.id.item_tags);
            cardViewLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.cardViewLayout);
            cardViewLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, ItemView.class);
            mcontext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code nothing happens when i click on a item and neither do I see any error in the logcat

Comment: kindly try to add the code for the fragment where this adapter is being used we see if there is away to solving the issue

Comment: What is `ItemView`?

Comment: I believe we should be posting the code that is specific to the problem we are facing from what is on some tos page here on SO. Actually as you can see I already have four answers meaning the people had an idea of what I was asking. Am good to go pal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was of the idea that on your application of the adapter in some activity you simply call the activity on the `setOnItemClickListener` of the adapter

```
private void loadItemsData() {
    RecyclerView itemsRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.posts_recycler_view);
    itemsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    itemsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    ItemAdapter myadapter = new ItemAdapter(new ArrayList<MyItem>(), getContext());

    myadapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, PostItems items) {
            ViewItem.passingIntent(getActivity(), items.postid);
        }
    });

    itemsRecyclerView.setAdapter(ListAdapter );
}
```

then once done that you come to the receiver activity and make way to get the variables being passed on to it

```
public static void passingIntent(Activity activity, Integer postid){
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ViewItem.class);
    intent.putExtra(MY_ITEM, postid);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

I have used this approach in one of my apps lately

Comment: What is `ListingAdapter`? What is `setItemOnClickListener` for a RecyclerView??

Comment: I think this answer is what I was looking for because despite a few errors on it it tends to fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can have a listener sent from the fragment to adapter. Instead of trying to start an activity from the adapter, you can send it back to the fragment to open the activity.

**1.** Define an interface

```
public interface MyAdapterListener {
   void openActivity(/*any values to be sent*/);
 }
```

**2.** The fragment should implement `MyAdapterListener`

**3.** send the listener object to an adapter in a constructor

```
ItemAdapter(ArrayList<ItemModel> mArrayList, MyAdapterListener listener) {..
         mListener = listener;
      }
```

**4.** On Adapter - View Holder: in `onClick()` return to fragment

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        mListener.openActivity(/*any values to be sent*/);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, try like this,

```
ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemModel> mArrayList) {
        this.mArrayList = mArrayList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listing_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}
```

In your fragment, while setting adapter

```
ItemAdapter itemAdapter=new ItemAdapter(getActivity(),itemList);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting your click listener in `onBindViewHolder` like below

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Glide.with(mcontext).load(mArrayList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.item_image);

    holder.item_name.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.item_description.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.item_tags.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getTags());

    holder.setOnClickListener(this) // put this line
    Log.d("MyAdapter", "position: " + position);
}
```

Then of course you will override `onClick` in adapter rather than `viewholder`

Comment: thanks I will try to implement your answer and see what i get as a result

Comment: your answer is kind of the same as what he just posted